# Clearing Recently used coordinate reference systems using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-2.10

After using some non usual SRC for demonstration purpose, I wish to clear my  "Recently used coordinate reference systems" list for the sake of praticity.

Is it possible?

I am using QGIS 2.10.1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### QGIS 2.x

Yes, you can enter the following code in the **Python console** to remove all *Recently used coordinate reference systems* from the user interface:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings

QSettings().remove('UI/recentProjections')
QSettings().remove('UI/recentProjectionsAuthId')
```

Now I'm not sure why exactly but, for me atleast, using one `remove` method was not enough. I had to use both (the order does not matter either aslong as both are used).

But it works for me anyway and hopefully for you too!

---

### QGIS 3.x

You could use the following:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings 
QSettings().remove('UI/recentProjections')
```

---

Or to import `QSettings` generically (i.e. from differing major QGIS versions), you could use the following (thanks to [@TeddyTedTed](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/98170/teddytedted)):

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings
```

Comment: Thanks Joseph, works great. I made a Feature Request for this to be included in the GUI, to facilitate the task for standard users.

Comment: @RASC - Awesome buddy, glad it works! There is an option to reset the `QSettings` which stores user interface settings which they could add the above function to.

Comment: Thanks @Joseph. For QGIS 3.x use  -  "from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings"

Comment: @TeddyTedTed - Thanks for your comment, that is certainly a more generic method instead of specifying `PyQt4` or `PyQt5` etc.

Comment: In QGIS 3.6.3 the second line is `QSettings().remove('UI/recentProjections')`

Comment: @aldeano - Thanks for your comment, edited post :)

Comment: None of the cited commands above are working for me (Qgis 3.10.2 on Windows 10). Can someone confirm it?

Comment: Same problem here: these aren't working for me with QGIS 3.20.

Answer (score 0):

This worked QGIS 3.22.1. It appears they changed `recentProjections` to `recentProjectionsWkt` at some point. To get it to work, I executed the following Python Commands:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings

QSettings().remove('UI/recentProjectionsWkt')

QSettings().remove('UI/recentProjectionsAuthId')
```

Comment: 3.30.2 this works beautifully, thanks. The earlier versions draw a blank.

Comment: Also works on 3.32.1 Lima...eventually!