# Delete CRS in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

Is there a way of deleting the various CRS's that QGIS lists? We are a Local Authority in England and the only CRS we need is British National Grid, which is set as the default, as well as Lat/Long for when we occasionally receive file from external partners.

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @SimonHume! According to the [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html#overview-of-projection-support), it is ill-advised to modify the database which contains all the CRS definitions. Instead, you could consider just deleting the recently used CRS by having a look at this post: [Clear “Recently used coordinate reference systems”](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163938/clear-recently-used-coordinate-reference-systems)